# Why is iOS Base64 encode result different with web online tool?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am encoding JPG image to Base64 on iOS. The result is no problem, however the result code is different with encoded by web online tools. Who cloud teaching me the reason.

---

### iOS source code:

```
    let image : UIImage = UIImage(named:"w1")!
    let imageData:NSData? =   UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)
    let encodeString:String = imageData!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
```

Also, I use web online tool to decode the result. It is no problem.

### Web tools :

- [Copyright 2016 Dynamic Drive ] http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/imagetobase64/
- [Wutils.com - Online web utility and help] http://base64.wutils.com/encoding-online/base64-encoder/

However, the iOS result code is different with encoded by web online tools.

Comment: Because you're re-encoding the image into a new JPEG file which will have different content than the original?

Comment: Get your image file url using Bundle method `url(forResource:` , get  your image data from that url `Data(contentsOf: URL)` and create your base64EncodedString from that.